# Using custom variables to group events in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, dom-events

My question is related to this unanswered one: [Google Analytics; using custom variables with events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316235/google-analytics-using-custom-variables-with-events)

On my page I have a video player that sends events to GA (eg: play, pause, etc).
In my Analytics account I would like to filter the data by title, series, program, user gender and age.

I tried sending custom variables like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'User Age', '20', 2 ]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Series', 'Series 1', 3 ]);
```

Unfortunately it seems like the events and custom variables aren't related.
Is there a way of tracking the number of pause events for a particular episode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the custom variables first, then call the event tracking code, all of that data should be captured by GA.  To report on it, you can filter by the custom variables.

See my data feed API query here:

- **Dimensions:** ga:eventAction,ga:eventCategory,ga:eventLabel
- **Metrics:** ga:totalEvents,ga:uniqueEvents
- **Filter:** ga:customVarName1==User Age;ga:customVarValue1==20

http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?dimensions=ga%253AeventAction%252Cga%253AeventCategory%252Cga%253AeventLabel&metrics=ga%253AtotalEvents%252Cga%253AuniqueEvents&filters=ga%253AcustomVarName1%253D%253DUser%2520Age%253Bga%253AcustomVarValue1%253D%253D20&start-date=2013-08-09&end-date=2013-08-23&max-results=50

Comment: Event tracking happens inside a flash file. I tried setting the custom variables before instantiating the flash player, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: It's working for events triggered on the same page, but I am sending the player events through the Brightcove Google Analytics plugin. Unfortunately it seems like they're being seen as two separate scripts.

Comment: I am not sure if you can do event tracking using that plugin, but you can call JavaScript from Flash.  Here is an example of how to track events in Google Analytics using the JavaScript - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204221/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-google-analytics-tracking-for-actionscript-2

Answer (score 1):

In `analytics.js` (I'm not using the older `ga.js` anymore, so I can't confirm), it's possible to use Custom Dimensions and Events together. I'm doing this for A/B testing.

Sending the custom dimension with an event is trivial:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', {
  'dimension5': 'myVideoName'
});
// ga is a tracker object.
```

Here, you can customize Category, Action (could add a Label too). You can also add extra dimensions.

Comment: I can't modify events that easily, because they are being triggered from a Flash file.